# How to import .env filein perl

Tags: linux, perl

I have two perl scripts `script1.pl` and `script2.pl` and I want to create one `environment.env` file which exports the environment variable and we can import `environment.env` file in both the scripts and use these environment variables

Is anybody knows how to implement this.

Comment: If you store the variable as Perl code, you can use `do`, e.g: `my $env = do './environment.env';`. Storing a variable can be done with Data::Dumper, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`Env::Modify`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Env::Modify) for tasks like this:

```
use Env::Modify 'source';
source("environment.env");
```